# How to intercept all calls to allocate and deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, profiling

I want all calls to allocate and deallocate memory to pass by me, so I can profile memory usage.  This means intercepting calls to `new` and `delete`, memory allocations by standard C++ containers, and if possible, memory allocations by separately compiled .lib libraries.

What is the easiest way I can achieve this without using another library?

Comment: It is possible to globally over-ride all standard versions of `operator new()` and `operator delete()`, and it is possible to specify your own allocators for standard containers IF you have control of the code that instantiates the containers.   However, if your code (or another library) uses a non-standard method (e.g. OS-specific APIs) to dynamically allocate or deallocate memory, then there is no standard way of intercepting those in standard C++ - other than by using OS specific techniques (or other libraries).

Comment: The easiest way to do this *globally*, for *all* kinds of allocations, that I can think of, would be to write a Linux kernel module.